# Grouping equal values from an array into subarrays

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, grouping

I have created an array that contains all of the values from one column of an excel spreadsheet. There are many values from that column that are equivalent.

I need to group all the values that are equal into individual arrays within the first array.

```
file_location = "C:\Users\Practice.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

Date = []

for i in range(sheet.nrows-1):    
    if [sheet.cell_value(i,0) == sheet.cell_value(i+1,0)]:
        Date.append(sheet.cell_value(i,0))  
    else:
        Date.append(sheet.cell_value(i,0))
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to break up the original array.

Comment: If they are equal why do you want to group them? It is a unique value, isn't it?

Comment: `if [sheet.cell_value(i,0) == sheet.cell_value(i+1,0)]:` is equivalent to `if (some non-emtpy list):` and that always is True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import xlrd, itertools

with xlrd.open_workbook("test.xlsx") as workbook:
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

    flat_data = (sheet.cell_value(i, 0) for i in range(sheet.nrows))
    grouped_data = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(flat_data)]
```

Or if you prefer a more "manual" approach, you can use `[-1]` to access the last group in the list of grouped data. Just compare the new value to one from that group, if any, or add a new group.

```
    grouped_data = [[]]
    for i in range(sheet.nrows):    
        d = sheet.cell_value(i, 0)
        if not grouped_data[-1] or grouped_data[-1][-1] == d:
            grouped_data[-1].append(d)
        else:
            grouped_data.append([d])
```

Both ways, `grouped_data` ends up as (for my `test.xlst`):

```
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0], [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], [6.0, 6.0]]
```